# How to click this row in selenium java?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, xpath

During my manual execution, I was able to select the row of "HTTP.BROWSER" by a single click.

Here is a screenshot of the web page:

[image: Screenshot]

The HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in $ctrl.pagedData track by $index" ng-class="[$ctrl.styles.circular, d.selected ? $ctrl.styles.selected : '']" ng-click="$ctrl.select($index)" class="ng-scope appSignatureModal__circular--Ny5Ib" style="">
        <div class="ellipsis appSignatureModal__modal-name-box--BiaO-" ng-class="$ctrl.styles.modalNameBox">
            <span class="app_icon app15893" ng-class="'app' + d.id" style=""></span>
            &nbsp;
            <span class="ellipsis ng-binding" ng-attr-title="{{d.name}}" title="HTTP.BROWSER">HTTP.BROWSER</span>
        </div>
        <div .../>
        <div .../>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I try to simulate the same thing using Java/Selenium, the targeted row was not picked?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'HTTP.BROWSER']//ancestor::li")).click();
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li//span[text() = 'HTTP.BROWSER']")).click();` working for you?

Comment: No, it does not work either.  But comparing with yours and mine, should such clicking  be  at the  "span" or "li" level ?

Comment: Usually both works. Is it a public website?

Comment: for either yours or mine, the script behaviors as if,  it hovers over the targeted row, but is not doing the actual "clicking".  Sorry it is not a public site.

Comment: Do you want to try javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with [Explicit wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#expected-conditions)

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Byxpath("//span[text() = 'HTTP.BROWSER']//ancestor::li")));
```

And also please check whether the element is in any frame or it is in the default content